# Why does my button stop working when I change the input type?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I used PayPal's button creator from their site and it gave me this code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-
DonationsBF:btn_donate_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image"src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0"src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

which is fine, and working. But what I want to do is change the button to btn-primary. 
So when I edit my input type from image to button, then change the "src" to class and inside my class have "btn btn-primary". The edited line looks like this:

```
<input type="button" src="btn btn-primary" border="0" name="submit">
```

I thought the only thing I was changing was the look of the button. Is there a specific way where I can get btn primary to reference PayPal instead of their donate button? Does the btn-primary **need** an href?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" border="0" name="submit">
```

type submit will submit the form.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"><button>Is this what you need?</button></a>
```